# Speed up Color Matrix

Tags: vb.net, image

I have managed to get the following working, just seems slow.  The following code will show the current image in the ribbon gallery dropdown with various Brightness/Contrast effects (like MS Word Picture Format has).
Question:  is it possible to have this code made quicker??  In Word, if i select image it is instant.  In my program it takes about 4 seconds??

Images from my ribbon.

[image: My Drop Down Gallery]

Here is the code that runs when I select one of the gallery images.  These are all in a class.  Code is VB.Net.

```
Image is selected, the RefreshGalleryFilterSelections called
Private Sub RefreshGalleryFilterSelections()

        Try
            'show image effects in picturebox
            Dim img As System.Drawing.Image = CType(PicOriginalPhoto.Image.Clone, Image)

            'Get the selected effect
            ClsFilterEditGroups.RefreshFilters(img)
            ClsFilterEditGroups.RefreshTransparencyFilters(img)

            ClsFilterEditGroups.RefreshCorrectionsFilters(img)

            ClsFilterEditGroups.RefreshPhotoColorFilters(img)

        Catch ex As Exception

            XtraMessageBox.Show(ex.Message, Application.ProductName & " - RefreshGalleryFilterSelections Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error)
            Err.Clear()

        End Try

    End Sub

Protected Overrides ReadOnly Property Matrix As ColorMatrix
        Get
            scale = 40.0F 'brightness
            translate = (-0.5F * scale + 0.5F) * 255.0F

            Dim value As Double = -40.0F 'contrast
            Dim FinalValue As Single = (CType(value, Single) / 255.0F)

            Return New ColorMatrix(New Single()() {
                   New Single() {1 + scale / 100, 0, 0, 0, translate},
                   New Single() {0, 1 + scale / 100, 0, 0, translate},
                   New Single() {0, 0, 1 + scale / 100, 0, translate},
                   New Single() {0, 0, 0, 1, 0},
                   New Single() {FinalValue, FinalValue, FinalValue, 0, 1}})
        End Get
End Property

 Protected Function ApplyMatrix(ByVal image As Image, ByVal size As Size, ByVal matrix As ColorMatrix) As Bitmap
        Dim src As New Bitmap(image, size)
        Dim dest As New Bitmap(src.Width, src.Height, PixelFormat.Format32bppArgb)
        Using graphics As Graphics = Graphics.FromImage(dest)
            Dim bmpAttributes As New ImageAttributes()
            bmpAttributes.SetColorMatrix(matrix)
            graphics.DrawImage(src, New Rectangle(0, 0, src.Width, src.Height), 0, 0, src.Width, src.Height, GraphicsUnit.Pixel, bmpAttributes)
        End Using

        src.Dispose()
        Return dest
 End Function
```

Appreciate any tips or better way to do this.  My first attempt.

Edit:  follow up to question, here is complete code for (1) of the ribbon filter types

```
Public Shared ReadOnly Property PreviewSize As Size
        Get
         'ImageSize is set on creation of gallery (32x32)
             Return FrmEdit.GalleryPhotoFilters.Gallery.ImageSize
        End Get
    End Property

 Public Shared Sub RefreshFilters(ByVal img As Image)
        FilterGroup.Items.Clear()
        For Each filter As FilterEditBase In FilterList
            FilterGroup.Items.Add(CreateGalleryItemFilter(img, filter))
        Next
    End Sub

  Protected Shared ReadOnly Property PictureEdit As PictureEdit
        Get
            Return FrmEdit.PicCurrentImage
        End Get
    End Property

    Public Shared Function CreateGalleryItemFilter(ByVal img As Image, ByVal filter As FilterEditBase) As GalleryItem
        Dim item As New GalleryItem() With {.Image = filter.ApplyFilter(img, PreviewSize), .Caption = filter.Name, .Tag = filter.Tag, .Hint = filter.Hint}
        AddHandler item.ItemClick, Sub() PictureEdit.Image = filter.ApplyFilter(img, img.Size)
        Return item
    End Function
```

```
'Now add filters to image on ribbon
 'Photo Filters (Sepia, Negative etc:)
    Protected Shared ReadOnly Property FilterList As List(Of FilterEditBase)
        Get
            If filterListCore Is Nothing Then
                filterListCore = New List(Of FilterEditBase)() From {New NewContrastFilterEditNormal(), New PolaroidFilterEdit(), New SepiaFilterEdit(), New NegativeGrayScaleFilterEdit(), New NegativeFilterEdit(), New GrayScaleFilterEdit(), New BWFilterEdit(), New ContrastedBWFilterEdit(), New White2AlphaFilterEdit(), New XRayFilterEdit(), New OldFashionLookFilterEdit()}
            End If

            Return filterListCore
        End Get
    End Property

'Base for all FilterList items
Public Class FilterEditBase

    Public Overridable ReadOnly Property Name As String
        Get
            Return String.Empty
        End Get
    End Property

    Public Overridable ReadOnly Property Tag As String
        Get
            Return String.Empty
        End Get
    End Property

    Public Overridable ReadOnly Property Hint As String
        Get
            Return String.Empty
        End Get
    End Property

    Public Function ApplyFilter(ByVal image As Image, ByVal size As Size) As Image
        Return ApplyMatrix(image, size, Matrix)
    End Function

    Protected Overridable ReadOnly Property Matrix As ColorMatrix
        Get
            Return New ColorMatrix()
        End Get
    End Property

    Protected Function ApplyMatrix(ByVal image As Image, ByVal size As Size, ByVal matrix As ColorMatrix) As Bitmap
        Dim src As New Bitmap(image, size)
        Dim dest As New Bitmap(src.Width, src.Height, PixelFormat.Format32bppArgb)
        Using graphics As Graphics = Graphics.FromImage(dest)
            Dim bmpAttributes As New ImageAttributes()
            bmpAttributes.SetColorMatrix(matrix)
            graphics.DrawImage(src, New Rectangle(0, 0, src.Width, src.Height), 0, 0, src.Width, src.Height, GraphicsUnit.Pixel, bmpAttributes)
        End Using

        src?.Dispose()
        Return dest
        dest?.Dispose()
    End Function

End Class

'Typical for each filter
Public Class SepiaFilterEdit
    Inherits FilterEditBase

    Public Overrides ReadOnly Property Name As String
        Get
            Return "Sepia Filter"
        End Get
    End Property

    Public Overrides ReadOnly Property Tag As String
        Get
            Return "sepiafilter"
        End Get
    End Property

    Public Overrides ReadOnly Property Hint As String
        Get
            Return "Sepia Filter"
        End Get
    End Property

    Protected Overrides ReadOnly Property Matrix As ColorMatrix
        Get
            Return New ColorMatrix(New Single()() {
                   New Single() {0.393F, 0.349F, 0.272F, 0, 0},
                   New Single() {0.769F, 0.686F, 0.534F, 0, 0},
                   New Single() {0.189F, 0.168F, 0.131F, 0, 0},
                   New Single() {0.0F, 0.0F, 0.0F, 1.0F, 0.0F},
                   New Single() {0.0F, 0.0F, 0.0F, 0.0F, 1.0F}})
        End Get
    End Property
End Class
```

Comment: Anything that has a dispose method should be disposed of. The easiest way is to use a _using_  statement as you did for _graphics_.

Comment: If it is operating on the full-size image every time and then shrinking it to the size to use in the ribbon, you could try making the thumbnail image once and apply the transforms to that.